MIME type errors with NGINX maintenance config and angular?
I have a maintenance config I created with nginx which I simply swap for my prod one. It is meant to call an index.html which is based on an Angular SPA and route to the /maintenance page created within the application.
If I use
try_files /index.html $uri $uri/;, I receive mime type errors in my browser's console (though in the network tab I'm getting 200 responses for the exact same files).
If I swap try_files /index.html $uri $uri/; with try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ; , I get a too many indirect error and its equivalent within the nginx logs.
Maintenance Config file
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    ##
    #Original IP Forwarding
    ##
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    server {
            listen       80 default_server;
            listen       [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name  _;
            return 301   https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mysite.com;
        root /etc/mysite/enabled-sites/ngbuild/browser; 

        location / {
            if ($uri != /maintenance) {
                return 302 https://$host/maintenance; 
            }
            try_files /index.html $uri $uri/;
        }

    }
    
}


Additionally, my prod config uses try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; for its locations which serves the production application just fine. If I swap that to try_files /index.html $uri $uri/; I then also get mime type errors in production.

Did you read the try_files directive documentation at all? The last argument in try_files is treated completely differently from the others:

If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.
...
The last parameter can also point to a named location ... Starting from version 0.7.51, the last parameter can also be a code.

An internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made is the key point here.
So what happens with your configuration? Using the
try_files /index.html $uri $uri/;
directive, you are causing all your asset requests - most importantly the /main.<build_id>.js request - to return the same index.html file. This response includes the Content-Type HTTP header set to text/html instead of the expected text/javascript. Of course, your browser will complain about the incorrect MIME type, but the main issue here is that your JavaScript file is not being retrieved at all.
Now, using the try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; directive more interesting things happen. Let's break it down:

Assume you receive a root request to your application. Since the requested URI is not /maintenance, a 302 redirect to /maintenance is issued.
Next, a /maintenance request is received. The most suitable location, which is the only location / { ... } block, is chosen to handle it. At this point, the $uri internal variable is equal to /maintenance, so no additional 302 redirect is issued this time. However, because maintenance is neither a physical file nor a directory, an internal redirect to /index.html occurs.
Now, nginx determines the most suitable location again (and, once again, it's the only location / { ... } block available). However, the $uri internal variable has now changed to /index.html. What happens next? Another 302 redirect is issued.

How this can be solved? Use the $request_uri variable instead, as its value does not change during internal redirects. Additionally, define two separate location blocks to ensure that your assets are loaded correctly:
location / {
    # all the asset requests will be handled here
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location = /index.html {
    if ($request_uri != /maintenance) {
        return 302 https://$host/maintenance; 
    }
}

